# PHP GET variable from another page

Tags: php

I have the following lines:

```
if(isset($_GET['search'])){
  $search_query = $_GET['user_query'];
```

The problem is that I am not trying to retrieve the get variable from this page, but rather from searchPage.php, which is a currently different page located within the same folder. So I would it to get the user_query variable from that page instead.  Where for instance, in that page I have:

```
searchPage.php?user_query=microsoft&search=search
```

If you need any clarification, let me know.

Comment: I don't it was neccessary to post the full code because this question is quite general, and not too specific. essentially I am trying to retrieve a variable from another php page.

Comment: put a header on your search.php page and pass it to your page with the GET variables.

Comment: could i do this where in the actual search page i insert the get code as a function in the header, and include that function within my code on the other page

Comment: There is no such thing as "getting a variable from another page". What you want to do is propagate data from one page to another via a GET request. If you construct the correct URL it should work. It's worth noting that if you were using a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) there would be a built-in facility for handling this illustrated by many examples.

Comment: thanks for your response, and clarification. could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Seems weird but if you must do it like this whats wrong with just redirecting from searchPage.php to the page where you want to get parameter to be eg

In searchPage.php

```
 header("Location:the_other_script.php?user_query=".$_GET['search']);
```

And in the_other_script.php

```
 if(isset($_GET['user_query']){
    $user_query = $_GET['user_query'];
 }
```

Begs the question why not just do your logic in searchPage.php? If you want to separate your code out just use a function call in searchPage.php.

EDIT:

So you have another script file called functions.php.. In this case just require this file in searchPage.php like..

```
require_once('the/path/to/functions.php');
```

and in your searchPage.php

```
 if(isset($_GET['user_query']){
    $returned_from_function = a_function_from_your_functions($_GET['user_query']);
    //do some stuff
 }
 //do some other stuff
```

In functions.php

```
 function a_function_from_your_functions($user_query){ 
  //do what you need to do 
  return $something; //optionally 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The problem is that I do not want the user to be redirected to another page. the search page is where all of the design element is. the function page is where all of the code is handled, and hence i do not want to redirect user to that page. All i want to grab the user_query (what they search) in the searchPage.php and use that variable information in the function page

Comment: as it stands, when use get['user_query'] as it is in the function page it tries to read it as such function.php/user_query= when that's irrealistic since that variable is only found in the search page

Comment: Your overcomplicating things I think. Check my edited answer. This is what functions were invented for

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. It unfortunately has to be complicated for various reasons. I do not want to include or require the function page in that page for various design reasons. I agree with your approach, but could you elaborate on a_function_from your functions and returned_from_functions

Comment: If you want to use your variable in a script in your functions file than you have to include it. Then just pass your variable to a function defined in your function file (in my question I called this `a_function_from_your_functions()` but you can call it anything). You can optionally return a value from this function to do some stuff with but you dont have to.

Comment: in that case wouldn't  be better to require the searchpage in the functions so i can reference it. sorry i am a bit lost

Comment: I accidentally added a new answer

Comment: thanks..this is too complicated than what it should be. I cannot include or require the function page into the searchpage for various reasons such as design. its really inside the function page. could i use session start where it stores the variables on the server and i can retrieve it somehow\

Comment: Its not complicated at all this is how you will have to do it. You can't just stick it in the session because you will never hit the script. You either need to make a http request to the script or call as a function or the code wontnrun

Comment: can you elaborate on the http request

Comment: You would either redirect the page as I initially suggested or make a request using PHP Curl. What reason could possibly discount using a require?

Comment: it just completly screws the design because it the function is reference but through javascript as it also used for pagination, and this whole search is designed to be dynamic. how would i make a request using php curl?

Comment: Look it up there is endless examples. If your app can't survive having a set of functions required then something is seriously wrong